# Generate random number % 10 == 0

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a simple game and I have a problem with generating values. I need to generate a number between 1 and 500, but only in the form of 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 etc. I have written such a function, but the numbers adjust once for an average of 100 page refreshments. How can I do this?

```js
console.log(generatePosition());

function generatePosition() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 1;
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 1;
   
    if (x % 10 == 0 && x % 10 == 0) {
        var cords = [x, y];
    }
   
    return cords;
}
```

Comment: Hint: Pick a number between 1 and 50 and multiply by ten.

Comment: jQuery is irrelevant here since it can't help you with random numbers.

Comment: @tadman thanks dude, your solution is really simple but its works so good :D

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would probably be to generate a random number between 1 and 50, and then multiply it by 10. As a result you will get only random numbers between 10 and 500, just as you wanted :-)

So, basically like this:

```
const randomInt = function (min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};

const randomNumberDivisibleBy10 = randomInt(1, 50) * 10;

console.log(randomNumberDivisibleBy10);
// => Something such as 10, 20, 30, …, 500
```

So, your function would look like this:

```
const generatePosition = function () {
  const x = randomInt(1, 50) * 10,
        y = randomInt(1, 50) * 10;

  const coordinates = [ x, y ];

  return coordinates;
};
```

Et voilà :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
function generatePosition() {

    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 1;
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 1;
    var x = x - (x % 10);
    var y = y - (y % 10);
    var cords = [x, y];

    return cords;

}
```

You can use this :)